# How to get background of each td in jquery?

Tags: jquery, django

I have a small problem with one function. Working on cinema app, currently on booking page. I have the table immitating the rows and numbers. One function changes the color of seat after click (actually double because it doesn;t work after one click, doesn't know why). Another function is responisble for gathering the data like row and number from highlited seats so it can be passed to views later on. The second function sees the elements in console.log, but when I want to get background colors, it returns undefined. Appreciate for any hints.

```
{% extends "main_templates/main.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
      <table class="table table-bordered ">
        <tbody>
          {% for row in seats_range %}
          <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="bg-danger">{{row}}</th>
            {% for number in seats_range %}
              <td class="text-center" style="width:5%;" value="{{row}}" onclick="change_bg(this)"><a href="#"></a>{{forloop.counter}}</a></td>
            {% endfor %} 
          </tr>
          {% endfor %} 
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" onclick="get_all_fields()">click me</button>



<script>

function change_bg(element){
  var color_to_change = "rgb(121, 12, 131)"
  $(element).click(()=>{
    console.log($(element).attr("value"))
    var color_now = $(element).css("background-color")
    if (color_now == color_to_change){
      color_to_change = "rgb(255, 0, 0)"
    }
    $(element).css("background-color", color_to_change)

  })
}

function get_all_fields(){
  var array = []
  var color_to_find = "rgb(255, 0, 0)"
  $(".table-bordered tbody td").each(()=>{
    let element_color = $(this).css("background-color")
    if(element_color == color_to_find){
      let element_row = $(this).attr("value")
      let element_number = $(this).text()
      let required_data = [element_row, element_number]
      array.push(required_data)
    }
  })
}
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You shouldn't bind an event handler in `change_bg`, you should just make the change. Putting the function on `onclick` already creates an event handler.

Comment: @sonic It comes from the argument in `onclick="change_bg(this)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`change_bg` shouldn't bind a click handler, since it's being called from `onclick`. It should just update the background immediately.

```
function change_bg(element) {
  var color_to_change = "rgb(121, 12, 131)"
  console.log($(element).attr("value"))
  var color_now = $(element).css("background-color")
  if (color_now == color_to_change) {
    color_to_change = "rgb(255, 0, 0)"
  }
  $(element).css("background-color", color_to_change)
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir :) Such an obvious mistake, but gave me a lot of trouble. I still can't display the highlited rows using second function. Can you see anything suspicious in the code ?

Comment: Do you mean `get_all_fields()`? It doesn't highlight anything. It just pushes data into an array, but doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: Yeah, I need to push the elements which background color have been set to red. To problem is that this function sees the elements when I print them in console, but when I try to get any of attributes I receive undefined.

Comment: You shouldn't use nonstandard attributes. `value` is not a standard attribute of `<td>` elements. If you need to add custom data to elements, use `data-XXX` attributes, which you can access with `.data()` in jQuery.

Comment: That's also a better way to get the selected rows, instead of using CSS.

Comment: $(".table-bordered tbody td").each(()=>{
    console.log($(this).data("value"))
  }) it returns 400 undefined so it sees the seats (20x20). Is there something wrong with bootstrap structure ?

Comment: Did you change `value="{{row}}"` do `data-value="{{row}}"`?

Comment: Just did it along with changing console.log($(this).data("data-value") and still the same :(

Comment: Don't use an arrow function in `.each()`. It doesn't pass `this`.

Comment: You are a start, it's working now :) Thank you a lot sir.